# llamar a un string de un metodo al main en java

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un código Java bastante sencillo. Se trata de un código que coge el texto de un documento.txt y lo convierte en un documento.HTML. Pero al crear el nuevo documento.html y querer poner el resultado dentro, no me deja poner el String textoFinal dentro del main. Alguien sabe porque no puedo llamar al String "textoFinal" en el main?

```java
    public class Prueba2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto = "";
        String ruta = "/Users/benji/Desktop/HTML/Prueba4";

        File Prueba4 = new File(ruta);
        Scanner sc;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(Prueba4);

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

                String lineaOriginal = sc.nextLine();

                texto = texto + lineaOriginal;
            }

            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        }
        System.out.println(texto);

        System.out.println(change(texto));

        FileOutputStream archivo;
        String text = "";
        PrintStream p;

        try {
            archivo = new FileOutputStream("/Users/benjicoll/Desktop/HTML/paginaPrueba.html");
            p = new PrintStream(archivo);
            p.println(text);
            p.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }

    }

    public static String change(String texto) {
        String textoFinal
                = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                + "<html>\n"
                + "    <head>\n"
                + "        <title>Title of Your Page</title>\n"
                + "    </head>\n"
                + "    \n"
                + "    <body><h1>";

        int s = 1;
        int c = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
            char letra = texto.charAt(i);
            textoFinal = textoFinal + Character.toString(letra);

            c++;
            if ((texto.charAt(i) == '.') && (c % 2 == 0)) {

                textoFinal = textoFinal + "<br>";
            }

            if (texto.charAt(i) == '.' && s == 1) {
                textoFinal = textoFinal + "</h1><h2>";
                s++;
                continue;
            }
            if (texto.charAt(i) == '.' && s == 2) {
                textoFinal = textoFinal + "</h2>";
                s++;
            }
        }
        return textoFinal + "\n" + "</body>" + "\n" + "</html>";

    }
}
```

Comment: Imagino que Prueba4 es un archivo que contiene el texto verdad?

Comment: Si! Prueba4 es un archivo donde contiene el texto del documento.txt, pero el problema es que no consigo poner ese texto en el String text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te escribe nada porque la variable `text` está vacía, debería ser:

```
        String text = change(texto);//asignar valor a la variable
        System.out.println(text);

        FileOutputStream archivo;
        PrintStream p;

        try {
            archivo = new FileOutputStream("/ruta/");
            p = new PrintStream(archivo);
            p.println(text);
            p.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Lobos. Ya funciona de maravilla!